# Stop called in state 1 error (-38, 0)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have the following code:

```
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(URL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
    mp.prepareAsync();
```

I'm doing the exact thing I should be doing in order to have the state of the media player correctly yet I'm still having the error:

> stop called in state 1 error (-38, 0)

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Update:
My code run ok with some link i found on web, but it cannot play my mp3 file on my server e.g link: http://111.blabla/wms/wp-content/upload/audio/mysong.mp3
Use VLC can play my file

Answer (score 0):

Error 38 means you are asking the MediaPlayer to do something when in the wrong state

Take a look at the mediaplayer state diagram on android documentation

[MediaPlayer state diagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram)

According to the diagram you have to call setDataSource() and prepare()
before calling start().

Probably something wrong happened before. Your logcat should point you in the right direction.

Since you are receiving the prepare async callback I guess that there is something wrong in datasource.

Your setDataSource looks a little bit strange since my expectaion is something like

```
setDataSource(currentConext, url)
```

and not just

```
setDataSource(url)
```

Comment: Can you provide your logcat? you can also try to attach the ErrorListener, it could provide you some useful info